# Matplotlib line plot line color by group

Tags: python, matplotlib

In `ggplot` if one need to plot two different group of data in different colors, one could do something like below

```
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))
```

This gives a dataframe like below

```
head(df2)
##   supp dose  len
## 1   VC D0.5  6.8
## 2   VC   D1 15.0
## 3   VC   D2 33.0
## 4   OJ D0.5  4.2
## 5   OJ   D1 10.0
## 6   OJ   D2 29.5
```

With this dataframe, to get `len` vs. `dose` for the two groups `VC` and `OJ`could be plotted in different colors like below.

```
gplot(df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=supp)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=supp))+
  geom_point(aes(color=supp))
```

This gives the below chart:

[image]

I was trying to use `matplotlib` in Jupyter Notebook to get a similar plot ( i.e. different colors for different groups ). But I couldn't find a way to specify the color by `group` (factor variable).

Note: Can't use seaborn lineplot as the AWS sagemaker instance I'm using gives `sns.__version__` `'0.8.1'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `seaborn` with `hue`:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data=df, x='dose', y='len', hue='supp')
```

output:

[image]

Comment: need `matplotlib` based solution as I can't use `seaborn` `lineplot` as the AWS sagemaker instance I'm using gives `sns.__version__`  `'0.8.1'`